# Как портируются игры?

Tags: разработка-игр

Расскажите как портируются игры. На любые платформы (без разницы).

P.S. нет, я не хочу этого делать, я вообще игры не делаю. Мне просто интересно, как этот процесс происходит.

Comment: берется исходный код игры и компилируется под новую платформу

Comment: Неужели все так легко? И даже нету никаких подводных камней?

Comment: подводные камни начинаются в процессе компиляции, когда для целевой платформы может отсутствовать вообще или иметь ограниченную функциональность необходимая библиотека.

Comment: И что в таких случаях делать?

Comment: искать/создавать альтернативу

Comment: Понятно, спасибо за разъяснение. Если нужно вы можете оставить ответ и он будет помечен как лучший(или как-то так).

Comment: Справедливости ради, перенос на новую платформу также сильно связан с системой пользовательского ввода и с оптимизациями под конкретную платформу. А еще игры - это не только исходный код, так что оптимизации в виде большего сжатия текстур/аудио, уменьшения разрешения видео/текстур тоже имеет место быть.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Зависит от того, на чём игра написана. Могу на своём примере сказать, как портировал игры с iOS на Android, написанные на C++.

Несколько типов проблем:

1. Проблемы с OpenGL. На Android поддержка различных экстеншенов для OpenGL зависит от вендора. Поэтому, если они у вас использовались, то, вероятно, придётся от них отказаться или проверять, есть ли они на устройстве и потом в зависимости от этого что-то делать (отключать часть функционала, заменять реализацию).
2. На C++ только код самой игры. Помимо этого нужно написать:

   1. Враперы. Базовый врапер на Java/Kotlin (если мы говорим про порт с iOS на Android). Там очень много проблем с жизненным циклом и контекстом GLSurface.
   2. Платфорозависимые штуки типо геймцентра, покупок и т.п.
3. В движке игры могут использоваться либы, которые плохо работают на другой платформе. К примеру, OpenAL хреново работал на Android для стриминга звука, пришлось переписать под Android на OpenSL ES. В то время даже на [гитхаб выкладывал](https://github.com/Suvitruf/Android-ndk/tree/master/OpenSLES).
4. Очень часто GUI делают средствами SDK. Если так, то при портировании всё GUI нужно, по сути, заново делать.
5. Проблемы с форматами аудио/видео. На каждой платформе свои стандарты.
6. Про работу с сетью вообще молчу.
7. Про сборку самих сорсов сейчас мало что могу сказать, т.к. вроде в этом плане всё лучше стало. В своё время мне приходилось .mk файлы ручками писать и линковать все файлы и библиотеки самому.

Так что, лучше про порт нынче не думать, а юзать изначально кроссплатформенные движки типа Unity и UE4.

Можете ещё почитать [мою статью про порт Dead Cells](https://suvitruf.ru/2019/05/08/5987/porting_dead_cells_to_mobile_an_indepth_breakdown/) (ну и вообще там про геймдев часто пишу, может ещё полезные для себя статьи найдёте). При порте с PC на мобильные платформы добавляется куча проблем с управлением и т.п.